# Which type of button should be used for 'OK' button in AlertDialog?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, android-button

I intend to create an `AlertDialog` with an 'OK' button. I know that there are 3 different kinds of buttons that can be used within an `AlertDialog`, but does anyone know which one should be used for an 'OK' button? I couldn't find anything about this in the Android guidelines.

**Option 1 (Positive button)**

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OK"){_,_ -> ...}
```

**Option 2 (Negative button)**

```
builder.setNegativeButton("OK"){_,_ -> ...}
```

**Option 3 (Neutral button)**

```
builder.setNeutralButton("OK"){_,_ -> ...}
```

Comment: Go with Option 1

Comment: it depends on the message of the alert, generally ok is used with positive button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The norm is to use the positive button position, which is positioned at the bottom-end of the Dialog (right for LTR, left for RTL).

You can put it wherever you want, really, since there aren't any guidelines, but I don't think I've ever seen a Dialog with only an OK button, with that button in the middle or on the left.

To avoid potentially confusing users, go with the norm.

Comment: I tend to use `neutral` for "OK", when there is no choice. It's just up to the developer to actually stick to some norm, indeed. Some ROMs display Positive differently from Negative, let alone the placement which should be positive on the right on Android.

Comment: @shkschneider personally, I'd be really confused seeing OK on the left of the dialog. But since it's only one button, I guess it really doesn't matter, because it's not like you can accidentally tap the wrong one.

Comment: Positive should be on the right. Neutral, when it's the only option, should take positive's place. Nothing positive or neutral should be on the left indeed ;)